# how to refactor traits bounds

Tags: rust, struct, traits

I have a struct with a very big traits bounds, that I have to re-write over every new trait implementation.

example:

```rust
pub struct MyStruct<T, K>
where
    T: PartialOrd + Debug + Clone + Copy,
    for<'a> K: 
        PartialOrd +
        Add<i32, Output = K> +
        Add<Output = K> +
        Sub<Output = K> +
        Mul<K, Output = K> +
        Mul<u32, Output = K> +
        Mul<i32, Output = K> +
        Mul<&'a K, Output = K> +
        Div<Output = K> +
        Div<&'a K, Output = K> +
        Clone +
        Copy +
        Debug,
    for<'a> &'a K:
        Sub<&'a K, Output = K> +
        Mul<i32, Output = K> +
        Mul<&'a K, Output = K> +
        Div<&'a K, Output = K>
{
    pub field1: T,
    pub field2: T,
    field3: K
}

impl<T, K> Trait1 for MyStruct<T, K>
where
    T: PartialOrd + Debug + Clone + Copy,
    for<'a> K: 
        PartialOrd +
        Add<i32, Output = K> +
        Add<Output = K> +
        Sub<Output = K> +
        Mul<K, Output = K> +
        Mul<u32, Output = K> +
        Mul<i32, Output = K> +
        Mul<&'a K, Output = K> +
        Div<Output = K> +
        Div<&'a K, Output = K> +
        Clone +
        Copy +
        Debug,
    for<'a> &'a K:
        Sub<&'a K, Output = K> +
        Mul<i32, Output = K> +
        Mul<&'a K, Output = K> +
        Div<&'a K, Output = K>
{ ... }

// etc ...
```

I would like to refactor my trait so that I can do something like :

```rust
pub type = MyBigTraitBound;

pub struct MyStruct<T, K>
where
    T: PartialOrd + Debug + Clone + Copy,
    K: MyBigTraitBound
{
    pub field1: T,
    pub field2: T,
    field3: K
}

impl<T, K> for MyStruct 
where
   T: PartialOrd + Debug + Clone + Copy,
   K: MyBigTraitBound
{ ... }
```

I already tried :

```rust
pub trait AnyNum<'a, K>
where
    K:
        'a +
        PartialOrd +
        Add<i32, Output = K> +
        Add<Output = K> +
        Sub<Output = K> +
        Mul<K, Output = K> +
        Mul<u32, Output = K> +
        Mul<i32, Output = K> +
        Mul<&'a K, Output = K> +
        Div<&'a K, Output = K> +
        Div<Output = K> +
        Clone +
        Copy +
        Debug,
    &'a K:
        Sub<&'a K, Output = K> +
        Mul<i32, Output = K> +
        Mul<&'a K, Output = K> +
        Div<&'a K, Output = K>
{}

pub MyStruct<'a, T, K>
where
   T: PartialdOrd + Debug + Clone + Copy,
   K: AnyNum<'a, K>
{ ... }
```

But I get many errors like if the trait bounds were not taken in consideration. Errors like:

- can't compare `K` with `K` - no implementation for `K < K` and `K > K`
- cannot add `i32` to `K` - no implementation for `K + i32`
- cannot multiply `K` by `&'a K` - no implementation for `K * &'a K`
- ...

So I am wondering, it is possible to refactor such trait bounds ? And how

Comment: I don't have reproducible code so I cannot verify, but it looks like you need HRTB (`for<'a>`) and not a generic parameter.